# Perform the same procedure three times simultaneously

Tags: php, performance, benchmarking

I made a PHP script to fetch Google some information about games and then I return the results and make the necessary treatments and perform other functions on top of the results.

I want to do the same search using Yahoo, Bing and 2 more search engines and need this to be done as quickly as possible, optimizing execution speed.

```
index.php = receives data search and call the file search.php 
search.php = calls all search scripts (google.php, yahoo.php, bing.php, etc ...) and after everyone ends their respective executions, calls the init.php file
init.php = has all the data of the other files, proceeds with the treatment and analysis of data
```

What is the best and fastest way to optimize perform this type of task in which I need to perform a "same procedure" (similar) and all at the same time to lower the speed of execution of the script.

Searching on Google, I found tips of people talking about `popen and pclose`, `wget or curl`, `shell_exec`, etc...

Not is an opinion question and yes technique about performance, if someone already has needed to do something similar that leave your answer and explain why it is the fastest way.

Comment: Take a look at curl_multi i.e. `curl_multi_*` in the PHP manual. Its a bit of a brain teaser initially, but when you get the concept it works like a dream. It might be overkill for just 3 simultaneous requests, but its worth a good look.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, already I use curl_multi_init a part of my project, it is really wonderful, I prepared a cache system and check for modified content, I'm trying to find a faster way internally, but if I do not find the internal way, I will have to use curl_multi_init again also for this step.